# I want to develop or find a repository that has stories for all Material UI components in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, storybook

I'm trying to import all MUI components stories in my storybook. Need a way to automate it so that it can automatically generate the stories or is there any repo that has ready made stories for all MUI components.

i tired creating a custom function that can write stories for me but still no luck

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the github repo of @mui/material, but there's no storybook in case of mui(i didn' expect that), but don' worry. i can help ya a bit.

1. clone the repo & extract components
   most of the components are in /material-ui/packages/mui-material/src/*, so we gotta take those components first and store em in our new directory.

or

1. fork the repo && get it locally && install the deps
2. ya'd find that in components we're importing few methods & libs, so install those libs in your central place i.e. your directory where ya've extracted those components.
3. install storybook as a dependency and now since mui contributors didn' write .stories.tsx files, ya'll have to write it(which's basically usin' those components and providin' options to the user to interact with the different layout & other options)
4. ya can even customize it however ya like & so n on

Note: writing stories can't be automated, it's a manual process, it's like building a webapp providing visual n interactive docs rather than the old plain text format. other steps can be done in one go with commands